# JSF Open new window and display bean data

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am running JSF 2.0 and the latest version of Primefaces 2.2RC1 I believe. I am trying to create a printer friendly window. When the user clicks on a p:commandLink I want a new window to open and display a xhtml file I have named printView.xhtml.

Now I can get the window working fine using JavaScript window.open but when I open the new window it will not render any values it just displays everything as #{myBean.value}. Does anyone know how to properly open a window and extend the current scope of the application into that window so I can call all of my managed beans properly and display the values etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

> *it just displays everything as #{myBean.value}*

So, the `FacesServlet` wasn't been invoked. It is the one responsible for doing the JSF works. You need to ensure that the URL in the `window.open()` matches the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`.

If it is for example `*.jsf`, then you need to open it as follows:

```
window.open('printView.jsf');
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with JSF 1, however my requrest is going through the JSF filter.

I've tried with JS using window.open, I've added a navigation case. My components are rendered, but there is no bean data.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, 2.2.RC1 had some bugs.  You'll want version 2.2.RC2.